# How do I blur the background

Tags: html, css

How do I blur the background but not the text, that sits on top of it?
This is how I want to display.

[image]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_blurred_bg

Comment: I'm afraid there's no easy, browser consistent way of doing it: caniuse.com/#search=backdrop-filter You can either decide to not use the effect for chrome and firefox or make it much more complicated and use canvas and javascript

Comment: I didn't downvote, but [here's why](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also, [here's how to "fix" your question](https://can-i-haz.codes).

Comment: People downvote, because your question shows _zero_ effort. Please go read [ask].

Comment: So the text is a part of the image or it's a panel above the background, post your code so we can help

Comment: Share you code so that we can understand what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

In the container which holds the text you can use transparent colors to blur more or less however you choose.

E.g

```
.container{
 color: white;
 background-color: rgba(140,140,140,0.5)
}
```

Transparency is measured from 0-1.

0 being fully transparent (invisible)
1 being opaque ( solid color)

Answer (score -1):

You must use two different containers for your image and your text and put them in a parent container, then use the absolute position for the text container and set a blur filter for your image container.

There is an example in the below: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_blurred_bg

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <style>
            body, html {
              height: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            
            * {
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            
            .bg-image {
              /* The image used */
              background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/nxkpa7oHRrc/maxresdefault.jpg");
              
              /* Add the blur effect */
              filter: blur(8px);
              -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
              
              /* Full height */
              height: 100%; 
              
              /* Center and scale the image nicely */
              background-position: center;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: cover;
            }
            
            /* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
            .bg-text {
              background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
              color: white;
              font-weight: bold;
              border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
              position: absolute;
              top: 50%;
              left: 50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
              z-index: 2;
              width: 80%;
              padding: 20px;
              text-align: center;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            
            <div class="bg-image"></div>
            
            <div class="bg-text">
              <h2>Blurred Background</h2>
              <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>
              <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
            </div>
            
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Okay, you can do copy&paste, too, great. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_blurred_background.asp

Comment: @04FS It was just for the code snippet, the answer has  a short description that I think it helps him